# How to Position a table/picture or both two pictures fixed on the top of a page in MS-Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

**I have two figures which are required to be positioned on the top or bottom in the same page in Word.**

I have tried the solution in http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/stop-fumbling-with-the-mouse-and-let-word-position-your-tables-for-you/, but it didn't totally work out for me. Both of my two pics went to the top positions in different pages. But I don't want them to be separated. In my case I have two pictures that I need to put them on the top of the same page, one following another.  So I have put my two pictures in a table (This is not required though), hoping to move them together onto the top position. Anyone can help me to achieve the requirement? My Word's versions are 2010 and 2013.
Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to place a text box where you want both figures and then paste them inside.  Use the formatting options to eliminate the border and adjust the margin around the figures.  Follow the instructions in the link you posted to ensure that the text doesn't go behind or in front of the figures.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to skip the table and use the picture formatting tool instead.

1. Insert your picture as you normally do.
2. Click on the picture one time to select it.
3. Choose Picture from the Format menu. Word displays the `Format Picture` dialog box.
4. Make sure the `Layout` tab is selected.
5. Select `behind text` or `in front of text` as your wrapping style.

This way you can drag to place the figures wherever you want in the document.
When you have placed the figures, you just move the text below the figures using the `Enter` key.

**Note:** You can get even more control over your figures by selecting for example `square`as your wrapping style, and then clicking on `advanced...`
Here you have to make sure the `picture position` tab is selected. Using this tool you can position the figures exactly where you want.

I hope this can help you out, and just ask if you need any more help.